# Errors update after installing ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, 18.04

I have already upgrade my ubuntu artful to bionic beta. But i got this errors after using command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
here's the error message:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up i2p (0.9.34-1ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/i2p.config: 14: /etc/default/i2p: RUN_AS_ROOT: not found
dpkg: error processing package i2p (--configure):
 installed i2p package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 i2p
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've been trying `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` it always come the same error.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

This will show the problem packages, then you can  just remove all the problem packages using

```
sudo apt remove sudo apt-get remove <package_name>
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: it also not works.